# Distributing an app with HockeyApp

Tags: ios, swift, hockeyapp

I was wondering: do I need an distribution certificate for my app, when I distribute it through HockeyApp?

I can't find any information about this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `Ad-Hoc` provisioning profile and a matching certificate.

See this Apple documentation with the section "Distributing Your App Using Ad Hoc Provisioning": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Answer (score 3):

Distributing Apps through HockeyApp is a way of shairing the development build. So you need to include the development provisional profile with the UDID of the devices in which the build is likely to be tested.

If you need information on adding more devices then you can refer the following link

http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/adding-new-devices-to-your-provisioning-profile

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use Enterprise certificates, creating an in-house provisioning profile (instead of Ad-Hoc) attached to an enterprise certificate, with no need to manage device UDIDs in that case.

The bad thing is that you'll need an Enterprise account and it's more expensive than the Developer one, about 299$ / year, but allow to distribute without provisioning devices.
https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

When you use those certificates and provisioning profiles, in hockey App you'll see this information in the Overview -> Provisioning section,

[image]